# Dragging DOMElement with a alpha PNG backgroundImage loses alpha

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, webkit, png

I have a number of block elements, styled with a background image that is transparent outside the shape of the image. It displays fine, but when I drag it in Google Chrome, it drags just fine but the alpha part of the backgroundImage displays as solid white.

```
.documents {
 background-image: url('foldedcorner_document-sprite.png');
 -webkit-user-drag: element; 
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 /* ... */
}
```

Is this a Chrome bug? I could've sworn I'd found a reference to it awhile back, but now that I'm trying to tackle it again I'm finding nothing by searching everywhere, nor am I having any luck. I can successfully assign a dragImage of the exact same PNG, but then I lose the content of the element I'm dragging, which is necessary to preserve during the drag.